# How to make MFC Ribbon Statusbar act like the regular CStatusBar

Tags: c++, mfc, statusbar, ribbon-control, capslock

The first image shows what I want to do. The second one shows what I get.

I want the status bar to show the state of the special keys CAPS LOCK, NUM LOCK and SCROLL LOCK. This image is from an old project using the CStatusBar.
This snapshot is from CMainFrame class.

[image]

This image shows how I am doing it in Visual C++ 2015 MFC and the results I get. This snapshot is from CMainFrame class, too.

[image]

My question is : Can anyone tell me how my application can intercept the change from toggle buttons CAPS LOCK and NUM LOCK then update the user interface.

I tried to use this code but it doesn't work :

```
ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_INDICATOR_STYLE, &CMainFrame::OnUpdateStyle)
ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_INDICATOR_FOLD, &CMainFrame::OnUpdateFold) 
ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_INDICATOR_OVR, &CMainFrame::OnUpdateInsert)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea why you'd think that posting **screenshots** of source code would be helpful. It certainly precludes pretty much all developers with impaired vision from even understanding your problem. Stop this insanity.

Comment: How can I improve this, please ?

Comment: By posting text as text, for starters. It's not like you pasted images into your code editor, or copied images out of your code editor. Just apply some common sense here.

Comment: I apologize. I thought the problem was in my code and wanted to explain more by posting images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the standard behavior of `CStatusBar` is not supported by `CMFCRibbonStatusBar`.

The good news is that it is very easy to implement the same behavior. 
Here is what you have to do in order to implement it in your application:

Add this to message map of your main frame class or child frame in case of MDI:

```
ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_INDICATOR_CAPS, &CMainFrame::OnUpdateButtonsState)
ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_INDICATOR_NUM, &CMainFrame::OnUpdateButtonsState)
ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_INDICATOR_SCRL, &CMainFrame::OnUpdateButtonsState)
```

The actual update handler should look like this:

```
void CMainFrame::OnUpdateButtonsState(CCmdUI* pCmdUI)
{
    UINT nVK;
    UINT flag = 0x0001;

    switch (pCmdUI->m_nID)
    {
    case ID_INDICATOR_CAPS:
        nVK = VK_CAPITAL;
        break;

    case ID_INDICATOR_NUM:
        nVK = VK_NUMLOCK;
        break;

    case ID_INDICATOR_SCRL:
        nVK = VK_SCROLL;
        break;

    case ID_INDICATOR_KANA:
        nVK = VK_KANA;
        break;

    default:
        TRACE(traceAppMsg, 0, "Warning: OnUpdateKeyIndicator - unknown indicator 0x%04X.\n",
            pCmdUI->m_nID);
        pCmdUI->ContinueRouting();
        return; // not for us
    }

    pCmdUI->SetCheck(::GetKeyState(nVK) & flag);        

}
```

Comment: Thanks, for your reply.

Comment: That's not working it's the CFrameWnd::OnUpdateKeyIndicator which is always called rather the one I defined like you suggested above.
The indicator get enabled/disabled in status bar when I press the key CAPS. I want it to appear/disappear.

Comment: Hurrrray! It's working now. I should move all the code to CChildFrame rather the CMainFrame. :)

Thank you a lot.

Comment: You did not mention you got MDI app. Anyways, I've updated the answer to cover MDI as well.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by moving the code to CChildFrame class.

```
ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_INDICATOR_CAPS, &CChildFrame::OnUpdateIndicators)
ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_INDICATOR_NUM, &CChildFrame::OnUpdateIndicators)
ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_INDICATOR_SCRL, &CChildFrame::OnUpdateIndicators)
```

And then

```
void CChildFrame::OnUpdateIndicators(CCmdUI *pCmdUI)
{
    pCmdUI->Enable();

    // ... the rest of the above code

    CString text;
    if (::GetKeyState(nVK) & flag)
        text.LoadStringW(pCmdUI->m_nID);
    pCmdUI->SetText(text);
}
```